# Correct method to calculate "Total wait time" of a session in oracle

Tags: performance, oracle, session, wait

**I need to find out the total time a session is waiting when its is active.**

For this i used the query like below...

```
SELECT (SUM (wait_time + time_waited) / 1000000)
  FROM v$active_session_history
 WHERE session_id = 614
```

But, i feel i'm not getting what i wanted using this query. 
Like, first time when i ran this query i got 145.980962, @ second time=145.953926and @3rd time i got 127.706429.

Ideally, the time should be same or increase. But, as you see, the value returned is reducing everytime.

Please correct me where i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not contain whole history, `v$active_session_history` "forgets" older lines. Think about it as a ring of buffers. Once all buffers are written, it restarts from 1st buffer. 
To get events of some session, look `v$session_event`. 
 To get current (active) event of active session: `v$session_wait` (In recent Oracle versions, you can find this info also in `v$session`) 
**NOTE:** v$session_event view will not show you CPU time (which is not event but can be seen in `v$active_session_history`). You can add it, for example, from `v$sesstat` if needed...

Answer (score 1):

Your bloomer is that you have not understood the nature of `v$active_session_history`: it is a *sample* not a log.  That is, each record in ASH is a point in time, and doesn't refer back to previous records.

Don't worry, it's a common mistake.

This is a particular problem with `WAIT_T`IME.  This is the total time waited for that specfic occurence of that event.  So if the wait event stretches across two samples, in the first record `WAIT_TIME` will be 1 (one second) and in the next sample it will be 2 (two seconds).  However, a `SUM(WAIT_TIME)` would produce a total of *3* which is too much. Of course this is an arithmetic proghression so if the wait event stretches to ten samples (ten seconds) a `SUM(WAIT_TIME)` would produce a total of 55.

Basically, `WAIT_TIME` is a flag - if it is 0 the session is ON CPU and if it's greater than zero it is WAITING.

`TIME_WAITED` is only populated when the event has stopped waiting.  So a `SUM(TIME_WAITED`) wouldn't give an inflated value.  In fact just the opposite: it will only be populated for wait events which were ongoing at the sample time.  So there can be lots of waits which fall between the interstices of the samples which won't show up in that SUM.

This is why ASH is good for highlighting big performance issues and bad for identifying background niggles.

So why doesn't the total time doesn't increase each time you run your query?  Because ASH is a circular buffer.  Older records get aged out to make way for new samples.  AWR stores a percentage of the ASH records on disk; they are accessible through `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESSION_HIST` (the default is one record in ten).  So probably ASH purged some samples with high wait times between the second and third times you ran your queries.  You could check that by including `MIN(SAMPLE_TIME)` in the select list.

Finally, bear in mind that SIDs get reused.  The primary key for identifying a session is `(SID, Serial#)`,  Your query only grouops by SID, so it may use data from several different sessions.

There is a useful presentation by Graham Woods, on of the Oracle gurus who worked on ASH called "Shifting through the ASHes".  Altough if would be better to hear Graham speaking, the slide deck on its own still provides some useful insights.  [Find it here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/manageability/ppt-active-session-history-129612.pdf).

**tl;dr**

ASH is a sample not a log.  Use it for COUNTs not SUMs.

---

> "Anything wrong in the way query these tables? "

As I said above, but perhaps didn't make clear enough, `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESSION_HIST` only holds a fraction of the records from ASH.  So it is even less meaningful to run `SUM()` on its columns than on the live ASH.

Whereas `V$SESSION_EVENT` is an actual log of events.  Its wait times are reliable and accurate.  That's why you pay the overhead of enabling [timed statistics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams245.htm#i1134696).  Having said which, `V$SESSION_EVENT` only gives us aggregated values per session, so it's not particularly useful in diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I queried `v$session_event` (filtered with sid) for a session and i got 3 hours for `direct path read temp` EVENT. But, on querying `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESSION_HIST` (filtered with `sid and serial#` and grouped by `EVENT` field) i get result in minutes for the same session. Anything wrong in the way I query these tables? Sorry, if its a very basic question I'm very newbie to internal arch. oracle.